# EF Stored Procedure. Map subquery in SELECT to List property

Tags: sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

Please help me to map a list of values in the SELECT to a List in the model

I have a query in stored procedure like this

```
SELECT Id, CustomerName, 
                    (
                            SELECT TOP(15) [Message]
                            FROM [dbo].[Messages] M
                            WHERE M.CustomerId = C.Id
                    ) AS CustomerMessages
          FROM [dbo].[Customers] C
```

I want this to be mapped to a model in my code

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public List<string> CustomerMessages { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using EF's SqlQuery method:

```
Database.SqlQuery<Customer>
```

The problem is that CustomerMessages is null after the stored procedure is invoked. What is the right way to achieve this mapping?

Answer (score 1):

The following will cause the query to return an empty string instead of NULL, which is a non-value.

```
SELECT Id, CustomerName, 
(
    SELECT TOP(15) COALESCE([Message], '')
        FROM [dbo].[Messages] M
    WHERE M.CustomerId = C.Id
 ) AS CustomerMessages
 FROM [dbo].[Customers] C
```

If `[Message`] IS NULL, the query will go to the next option in the COALESCE which is '' (empty string).  This will not allow NULL to be returned by the query.  I often use this technique when creating Excel reports for my users so they don't have to deal with NULL in the result sets.